# How to compute (and check) this transform matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

**Background:**
This is a homework exercise which asks to compute a transform matrix. The answer has been published by our teacher. However, my approach goes a different way and gets a different solution. I checked over and over, but failed to identify the error.

**The Exercise Problem:**
Suppose $X \in R^{2 \times 2}$, define a linear transformation over $R^{2 \times 2}$ as: $ \mathbf{T(X)} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 \\ \end{bmatrix} X$.
Please compute its transform matrix under the following basis: $\mathbf{E_1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$, $\mathbf{E_2} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$, $\mathbf{E_3} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$, $\mathbf{E_4} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$.

**My solution:** My approach is simply to transform each of the vectors of the basis by $T$, then insert the result into the columns of a matrix.
      \begin{cases}
        T(E_1) &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 \\ \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}
        = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} = E_1 - 2E_3 + 2E_4.
        \\[15pt]
        T(E_2) &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 \\ \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}
        = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 \\ \end{bmatrix} = -E_2 + 2E_4.
        \\[15pt]
        T(E_3) &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 \\ \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}
  = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 4 \\ \end{bmatrix} = -E_1 - 2E_2 + 2E_3 + 2E_4.
  \\[15pt]
  T(E_4) &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 \\ \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \\\end{bmatrix}
  = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 4 & 4 \\ \end{bmatrix} = -2E_2 + E_4.  
      \end{cases}
  Thus, the transform matrix of $T$ is:
    $B = \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
      0 & -2 & -2 & -2 \\
      -2 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
      2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$.

**My teacher's solution:**
This approach first computes the transform matrix of $T$ under the *natural basis* of $R^{2 \times 2}$, that is, $\mathbf{E_{11}} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$, $\mathbf{E_{12}} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$, $\mathbf{E_{21}} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$, $\mathbf{E_{22}} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$. 
      \begin{cases}
        T(E_{11}) &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 \\ \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}
        = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} = E_{11} + 0 E_{12} + 2E_{21} + 0E_{22}.
        \\[15pt]
        T(E_{12}) &= 0 E_{11} + E_{12} + 0 E_{21} + 2E_{22}.
        \\[15pt]
        T(E_{21}) &= E_{11} + 0 E_{12} + 2E_{21} + 0 E_{22}.
        \\[15pt]
        T(E_4) &= 0 E_{11} + 1 E_{12} + 0 E_{21} + 2E_{22}.  
      \end{cases}
Therefore,
        $T(E_{11},E_{12},E_{21},E_{22}) = (E_{11},E_{12},E_{21},E_{22}) \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix} = (E_{11},E_{12},E_{21},E_{22}) A$.
It then takes advantage of the transform matrix $C$ from the natural basis to the target basis:
$C = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

So, the transform matrix of $T$ under the target basis is:
$B = C^{-1}AC = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -2 & -1 & -3 & -2 \\ 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$.

**My Question:**

> 1. As you can see, the two answers are different. Then, what is wrong with my solution?
> 2. How to check whether a transform matrix has been correctly computed without the teacher's answer?

Comment: Q2 – how to check the answer – is a sensible question to ask; after all in future you need to be able to get it right without help (if you need to apply this knowledge at all). The most obvious thing to do seems to be to apply the matrix you are checking to each element of the basis and check that it yields $ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 \\ \end{bmatrix} E_i $ in each case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is correct but $E_1 - 2 E_3 + E_4 $ is not what you want
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} 
- 2  \begin{bmatrix} 1 &1 \\ 1 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} 
+ 2 \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\\ \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 &2 \\ \end{bmatrix} \neq 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2\\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$
It was just a computational error.
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} 
- 2  \begin{bmatrix} 1 &1 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} 
+ 2 \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 2 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$
This is what your teacher has.

Comment: What am I doing when checking it over and over...?! Thanks.

Comment: Happens. We are all *great* at spotting other people's mistakes :)

Comment: How does this answer #2 - conveniently what I was wondering ;)?

Comment: @MikeWeir: see my comment on the question.